# video recording using camera 2

Tags: java, android, android-camera2, mediarecorder

I am trying to record video using media recorder and camera2 but the app crashes as soon as `mediarecorder.start()` function is encountered. In the `oncreate` first `prepareCamera` is called and then `trigger` is called. I am a bit new to camera2. Can anyone help me find out why it is happening so?

```
 public void prepareCamera() throws CameraAccessException {
    manager = (CameraManager) getSystemService(CAMERA_SERVICE);
    String[] cameras = manager.getCameraIdList();
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        Log.v("mycontroller","permission not granted");
        return;
    }
    Log.v("mycontroller","permission granted "+cameras[0]);
    manager.openCamera(cameras[0], new CameraDevice.StateCallback(){
        @Override
        public void onOpened(CameraDevice camera) {
            Log.v("mycontroller","camera opened");
            mCamera2 = camera;
            mediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.SURFACE);
            mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
            mediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.MPEG_4_SP);
            try {
                mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(createFile().getAbsolutePath());
                mediaRecorder.prepare();
                Log.v("mycontroller","recorder prepared");
                List<Surface> list = new ArrayList<>();
                list.add(mediaRecorder.getSurface());
                final CaptureRequest.Builder captureRequest = mCamera2.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_RECORD);
                captureRequest.addTarget(mediaRecorder.getSurface());
                mCaptureRequest = captureRequest.build();
                mCamera2.createCaptureSession(list, new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback(){
                    @Override
                    public void onConfigured(CameraCaptureSession session) {
                        mSession = session;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onConfigureFailed(CameraCaptureSession session) {
                        mSession = session;
                    }
                }, null);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onDisconnected(CameraDevice camera) {}
        @Override
        public void onError(CameraDevice camera, int error) {}
    }, null);
}
public void trigger() {
    try {
            mediaRecorder.start();
            mSession.setRepeatingRequest(mCaptureRequest,
                    new CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCaptureStarted(CameraCaptureSession session, CaptureRequest request, long timestamp, long frameNumber) {
                            Log.v("mycontroller","camera started capturing");
                            super.onCaptureStarted(session, request, timestamp, frameNumber);
                        }
                        @Override
                        public void onCaptureCompleted(CameraCaptureSession session, CaptureRequest request, TotalCaptureResult result) {
                            Log.v("mycontroller","camera stoped capturing");
                            super.onCaptureCompleted(session, request, result);
                        }
                    }, null);
    } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
        Log.v("mycontroller",e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void releaseMediaRecorder() throws CameraAccessException {
    mSession.stopRepeating();
    try {
        mediaRecorder.stop();
        mediaRecorder.reset();
        mediaRecorder.release();
    }
    catch (Exception e){}
    mediaRecorder= null;
    mCamera2=null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Google's Camera2Video sample to see if you can find any critical differences between your code and the sample:

https://github.com/googlearchive/android-Camera2Video/tree/master/Application/src/main/java/com/example/android/camera2video

You may need to set more MediaRecorder settings like resolution; often the [CamcorderProfile](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/media/CamcorderProfile) class is used to do this easily.